# MFC equivalent for STL std::map

Tags: c++, windows, dictionary, stl, mfc

I need to associate strings to FILE pointers, and strings to unsigned long integers. Using the STL i would simply do :

```
map<string, FILE *>
map<string, unsigned long int>
```

But i don't understand how to do the equivalent with MFC CMap.

I tried :

```
CMap<string, string &, FILE *, FILE * &>
CMap<string, string *, FILE *, FILE **>
```

But i'm getting errors in both cases :
error c2440 typecast cannot convert from std string to DWORD_PTR

Also i'm not sure to understand the logic of having 4 template parameters.

Can anyone explain me please ? Thank you.

Comment: Why not continue to use a `std::map`? It's not incompatible with MFC.

Comment: Because STL maps are not supported correctly on EVC4, not because i like to make my life complicated on purpose.

Comment: Oh, I see - you didn't mention eVC4 in your question, but I guess you've got your answer now anyway - hope it goes well ...

Comment: Yeah well i thought i had it, but i don't :( The compiler keeps yelling and says there are not enough template parameters now :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CMap<string, FILE*>
```

and

```
CMap<string, unsigned long>
```

should work fine. The version using 4 parameters is for specialized scenarios only.

Comment: I just noticed that the compiler says there is too few arguments to the template, so they are mandatory after all.

Comment: I don't have a compiler at hand, could have sworn I never used the long version. Anyway, a map from string to filepointer could look like this: CMap<CString, LPCTSTR, FILE*, FILE*>. Note that you don't need a special reference type, if your type in question is easily copyable without performance loss. I had wierd problems mixing MCF and STL so I would suggest using the MCF string class with other MFC classes.

Comment: The last argument must be a reference because it is used in CMap::Lookup() and CMap::GetNextAssoc() to retrieve a mapped value.

ie. CMap<CString, LPCTSTR, FILE*, FILE*&>